# TimeZone ID's in Java

Tags: java, timezone

I'm having weird problem with java TimeZone..

Calling **TimeZone.getDefault()** gives my local time zone, which has an ID "GMT+02:00".
Funny thing is that this ID doesn't appear in a list provided by **TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()**. Apparently my zone appears to be "Etc/GMT+2".

I'm trying to populate a combo with time zones, but it's impossible to put a selection because GMT+02:00 is not in the list..
Anyone seen this problem? Any ideas?

---

Update:

The bottom line is - can't rely on ID strings, must go with the offset as display ID's may vary from system to system.

Comment: How do you populate that combo? With `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`?

Comment: Yes. Actually the problem popped up after we moved to the latest release of Java6. It use to work before, I don't remember which release was it.. Now it definitely brings me to the point to avoid using getAvailableIDs and stick to a simple list with offsets.

Comment: If automatic daylight saving is not desired, that's ok indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking back on some other SO questions, this seems to be a Java-on-Windows problem. Please have a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583141/how-to-use-java-timezone-id-in-a-windows-non-java-application), especially answer 1, which points to a wikipedia link that may solve your mapping issue.

Answer (score 35):

GMT+02:00 is a custom ID, it won't appear in the output of `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` (which is huge). What you could do is to ask the user to specify his offset first and then get the available IDs for the given offset. For example, for GMT+02:00, the following piece of code:

```
for (String string : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(TimeZone.getTimeZone(
        "GMT+02:00").getRawOffset())) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

gives the following output:

```
ART
Africa/Blantyre
Africa/Bujumbura
Africa/Cairo
Africa/Gaborone
Africa/Harare
Africa/Johannesburg
Africa/Kigali
Africa/Lubumbashi
Africa/Lusaka
Africa/Maputo
Africa/Maseru
Africa/Mbabane
Africa/Tripoli
Asia/Amman
Asia/Beirut
Asia/Damascus
Asia/Gaza
Asia/Istanbul
Asia/Jerusalem
Asia/Nicosia
Asia/Tel_Aviv
CAT
EET
Egypt
Etc/GMT-2
Europe/Athens
Europe/Bucharest
Europe/Chisinau
Europe/Helsinki
Europe/Istanbul
Europe/Kaliningrad
Europe/Kiev
Europe/Mariehamn
Europe/Minsk
Europe/Nicosia
Europe/Riga
Europe/Simferopol
Europe/Sofia
Europe/Tallinn
Europe/Tiraspol
Europe/Uzhgorod
Europe/Vilnius
Europe/Zaporozhye
Israel
Libya
Turkey
```

It's still big but human browsable this time.

Comment: Thanks. In this link it's possible to see others: http://www.codereye.com/2009/05/getting-time-zone-list-in-java.html

Answer (score 9):

## `java.time.ZoneId`

`TimeZone` is part of the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

In your case, look at [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) and `ZoneOffset`. An offset-from-UTC is a number of hours and minutes. A time zone is a history of past, present, and future offsets in use by a region over various periods of time.

Get a collection of all known zones via [`ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#getAvailableZoneIds--). Be sure your JVM has been updated recently enough with info about all time zones in which you have an interest. Politicians have a surprising propensity for frequently changing zone definitions, often with little forewarning.

```
Set < String > ids = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds() ;
```

As of Java 8 Update 144.

> [Asia/Aden, America/Cuiaba, Etc/GMT+9, Etc/GMT+8, Africa/Nairobi, America/Marigot, Asia/Aqtau, Pacific/Kwajalein, America/El_Salvador, Asia/Pontianak, Africa/Cairo, Pacific/Pago_Pago, Africa/Mbabane, Asia/Kuching, Pacific/Honolulu, Pacific/Rarotonga, America/Guatemala, Australia/Hobart, Europe/London, America/Belize, America/Panama, Asia/Chungking, America/Managua, America/Indiana/Petersburg, Asia/Yerevan, Europe/Brussels, GMT, Europe/Warsaw, America/Chicago, Asia/Kashgar, Chile/Continental, Pacific/Yap, CET, Etc/GMT-1, Etc/GMT-0, Europe/Jersey, America/Tegucigalpa, Etc/GMT-5, Europe/Istanbul, America/Eirunepe, Etc/GMT-4, America/Miquelon, Etc/GMT-3, Europe/Luxembourg, Etc/GMT-2, Etc/GMT-9, America/Argentina/Catamarca, Etc/GMT-8, Etc/GMT-7, Etc/GMT-6, Europe/Zaporozhye, Canada/Yukon, Canada/Atlantic, Atlantic/St_Helena, Australia/Tasmania, Libya, Europe/Guernsey, America/Grand_Turk, US/Pacific-New, Asia/Samarkand, America/Argentina/Cordoba, Asia/Phnom_Penh, Africa/Kigali, Asia/Almaty, US/Alaska, Asia/Dubai, Europe/Isle_of_Man, America/Araguaina, Cuba, Asia/Novosibirsk, America/Argentina/Salta, Etc/GMT+3, Africa/Tunis, Etc/GMT+2, Etc/GMT+1, Pacific/Fakaofo, Africa/Tripoli, Etc/GMT+0, Israel, Africa/Banjul, Etc/GMT+7, Indian/Comoro, Etc/GMT+6, Etc/GMT+5, Etc/GMT+4, Pacific/Port_Moresby, US/Arizona, Antarctica/Syowa, Indian/Reunion, Pacific/Palau, Europe/Kaliningrad, America/Montevideo, Africa/Windhoek, Asia/Karachi, Africa/Mogadishu, Australia/Perth, Brazil/East, Etc/GMT, Asia/Chita, Pacific/Easter, Antarctica/Davis, Antarctica/McMurdo, Asia/Macao, America/Manaus, Africa/Freetown, Europe/Bucharest, Asia/Tomsk, America/Argentina/Mendoza, Asia/Macau, Europe/Malta, Mexico/BajaSur, Pacific/Tahiti, Africa/Asmera, Europe/Busingen, America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos, Africa/Malabo, Europe/Skopje, America/Catamarca, America/Godthab, Europe/Sarajevo, Australia/ACT, GB-Eire, Africa/Lagos, America/Cordoba, Europe/Rome, Asia/Dacca, Indian/Mauritius, Pacific/Samoa, America/Regina, America/Fort_Wayne, America/Dawson_Creek, Africa/Algiers, Europe/Mariehamn, America/St_Johns, America/St_Thomas, Europe/Zurich, America/Anguilla, Asia/Dili, America/Denver, Africa/Bamako, Europe/Saratov, GB, Mexico/General, Pacific/Wallis, Europe/Gibraltar, Africa/Conakry, Africa/Lubumbashi, Asia/Istanbul, America/Havana, NZ-CHAT, Asia/Choibalsan, America/Porto_Acre, Asia/Omsk, Europe/Vaduz, US/Michigan, Asia/Dhaka, America/Barbados, Europe/Tiraspol, Atlantic/Cape_Verde, Asia/Yekaterinburg, America/Louisville, Pacific/Johnston, Pacific/Chatham, Europe/Ljubljana, America/Sao_Paulo, Asia/Jayapura, America/Curacao, Asia/Dushanbe, America/Guyana, America/Guayaquil, America/Martinique, Portugal, Europe/Berlin, Europe/Moscow, Europe/Chisinau, America/Puerto_Rico, America/Rankin_Inlet, Pacific/Ponape, Europe/Stockholm, Europe/Budapest, America/Argentina/Jujuy, Australia/Eucla, Asia/Shanghai, Universal, Europe/Zagreb, America/Port_of_Spain, Europe/Helsinki, Asia/Beirut, Asia/Tel_Aviv, Pacific/Bougainville, US/Central, Africa/Sao_Tome, Indian/Chagos, America/Cayenne, Asia/Yakutsk, Pacific/Galapagos, Australia/North, Europe/Paris, Africa/Ndjamena, Pacific/Fiji, America/Rainy_River, Indian/Maldives, Australia/Yancowinna, SystemV/AST4, Asia/Oral, America/Yellowknife, Pacific/Enderbury, America/Juneau, Australia/Victoria, America/Indiana/Vevay, Asia/Tashkent, Asia/Jakarta, Africa/Ceuta, Asia/Barnaul, America/Recife, America/Buenos_Aires, America/Noronha, America/Swift_Current, Australia/Adelaide, America/Metlakatla, Africa/Djibouti, America/Paramaribo, Europe/Simferopol, Europe/Sofia, Africa/Nouakchott, Europe/Prague, America/Indiana/Vincennes, Antarctica/Mawson, America/Kralendijk, Antarctica/Troll, Europe/Samara, Indian/Christmas, America/Antigua, Pacific/Gambier, America/Indianapolis, America/Inuvik, America/Iqaluit, Pacific/Funafuti, UTC, Antarctica/Macquarie, Canada/Pacific, America/Moncton, Africa/Gaborone, Pacific/Chuuk, Asia/Pyongyang, America/St_Vincent, Asia/Gaza, Etc/Universal, PST8PDT, Atlantic/Faeroe, Asia/Qyzylorda, Canada/Newfoundland, America/Kentucky/Louisville, America/Yakutat, Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh, Antarctica/Casey, Europe/Copenhagen, Africa/Asmara, Atlantic/Azores, Europe/Vienna, ROK, Pacific/Pitcairn, America/Mazatlan, Australia/Queensland, Pacific/Nauru, Europe/Tirane, Asia/Kolkata, SystemV/MST7, Australia/Canberra, MET, Australia/Broken_Hill, Europe/Riga, America/Dominica, Africa/Abidjan, America/Mendoza, America/Santarem, Kwajalein, America/Asuncion, Asia/Ulan_Bator, NZ, America/Boise, Australia/Currie, EST5EDT, Pacific/Guam, Pacific/Wake, Atlantic/Bermuda, America/Costa_Rica, America/Dawson, Asia/Chongqing, Eire, Europe/Amsterdam, America/Indiana/Knox, America/North_Dakota/Beulah, Africa/Accra, Atlantic/Faroe, Mexico/BajaNorte, America/Maceio, Etc/UCT, Pacific/Apia, GMT0, America/Atka, Pacific/Niue, Canada/East-Saskatchewan, Australia/Lord_Howe, Europe/Dublin, Pacific/Truk, MST7MDT, America/Monterrey, America/Nassau, America/Jamaica, Asia/Bishkek, America/Atikokan, Atlantic/Stanley, Australia/NSW, US/Hawaii, SystemV/CST6, Indian/Mahe, Asia/Aqtobe, America/Sitka, Asia/Vladivostok, Africa/Libreville, Africa/Maputo, Zulu, America/Kentucky/Monticello, Africa/El_Aaiun, Africa/Ouagadougou, America/Coral_Harbour, Pacific/Marquesas, Brazil/West, America/Aruba, America/North_Dakota/Center, America/Cayman, Asia/Ulaanbaatar, Asia/Baghdad, Europe/San_Marino, America/Indiana/Tell_City, America/Tijuana, Pacific/Saipan, SystemV/YST9, Africa/Douala, America/Chihuahua, America/Ojinaga, Asia/Hovd, America/Anchorage, Chile/EasterIsland, America/Halifax, Antarctica/Rothera, America/Indiana/Indianapolis, US/Mountain, Asia/Damascus, America/Argentina/San_Luis, America/Santiago, Asia/Baku, America/Argentina/Ushuaia, Atlantic/Reykjavik, Africa/Brazzaville, Africa/Porto-Novo, America/La_Paz, Antarctica/DumontDUrville, Asia/Taipei, Antarctica/South_Pole, Asia/Manila, Asia/Bangkok, Africa/Dar_es_Salaam, Poland, Atlantic/Madeira, Antarctica/Palmer, America/Thunder_Bay, Africa/Addis_Ababa, Asia/Yangon, Europe/Uzhgorod, Brazil/DeNoronha, Asia/Ashkhabad, Etc/Zulu, America/Indiana/Marengo, America/Creston, America/Punta_Arenas, America/Mexico_City, Antarctica/Vostok, Asia/Jerusalem, Europe/Andorra, US/Samoa, PRC, Asia/Vientiane, Pacific/Kiritimati, America/Matamoros, America/Blanc-Sablon, Asia/Riyadh, Iceland, Pacific/Pohnpei, Asia/Ujung_Pandang, Atlantic/South_Georgia, Europe/Lisbon, Asia/Harbin, Europe/Oslo, Asia/Novokuznetsk, CST6CDT, Atlantic/Canary, America/Knox_IN, Asia/Kuwait, SystemV/HST10, Pacific/Efate, Africa/Lome, America/Bogota, America/Menominee, America/Adak, Pacific/Norfolk, Europe/Kirov, America/Resolute, Pacific/Tarawa, Africa/Kampala, Asia/Krasnoyarsk, Greenwich, SystemV/EST5, America/Edmonton, Europe/Podgorica, Australia/South, Canada/Central, Africa/Bujumbura, America/Santo_Domingo, US/Eastern, Europe/Minsk, Pacific/Auckland, Africa/Casablanca, America/Glace_Bay, Canada/Eastern, Asia/Qatar, Europe/Kiev, Singapore, Asia/Magadan, SystemV/PST8, America/Port-au-Prince, Europe/Belfast, America/St_Barthelemy, Asia/Ashgabat, Africa/Luanda, America/Nipigon, Atlantic/Jan_Mayen, Brazil/Acre, Asia/Muscat, Asia/Bahrain, Europe/Vilnius, America/Fortaleza, Etc/GMT0, US/East-Indiana, America/Hermosillo, America/Cancun, Africa/Maseru, Pacific/Kosrae, Africa/Kinshasa, Asia/Kathmandu, Asia/Seoul, Australia/Sydney, America/Lima, Australia/LHI, America/St_Lucia, Europe/Madrid, America/Bahia_Banderas, America/Montserrat, Asia/Brunei, America/Santa_Isabel, Canada/Mountain, America/Cambridge_Bay, Asia/Colombo, Australia/West, Indian/Antananarivo, Australia/Brisbane, Indian/Mayotte, US/Indiana-Starke, Asia/Urumqi, US/Aleutian, Europe/Volgograd, America/Lower_Princes, America/Vancouver, Africa/Blantyre, America/Rio_Branco, America/Danmarkshavn, America/Detroit, America/Thule, Africa/Lusaka, Asia/Hong_Kong, Iran, America/Argentina/La_Rioja, Africa/Dakar, SystemV/CST6CDT, America/Tortola, America/Porto_Velho, Asia/Sakhalin, Etc/GMT+10, America/Scoresbysund, Asia/Kamchatka, Asia/Thimbu, Africa/Harare, Etc/GMT+12, Etc/GMT+11, Navajo, America/Nome, Europe/Tallinn, Turkey, Africa/Khartoum, Africa/Johannesburg, Africa/Bangui, Europe/Belgrade, Jamaica, Africa/Bissau, Asia/Tehran, WET, Europe/Astrakhan, Africa/Juba, America/Campo_Grande, America/Belem, Etc/Greenwich, Asia/Saigon, America/Ensenada, Pacific/Midway, America/Jujuy, Africa/Timbuktu, America/Bahia, America/Goose_Bay, America/Virgin, America/Pangnirtung, Asia/Katmandu, America/Phoenix, Africa/Niamey, America/Whitehorse, Pacific/Noumea, Asia/Tbilisi, America/Montreal, Asia/Makassar, America/Argentina/San_Juan, Hongkong, UCT, Asia/Nicosia, America/Indiana/Winamac, SystemV/MST7MDT, America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia, America/Boa_Vista, America/Grenada, Asia/Atyrau, Australia/Darwin, Asia/Khandyga, Asia/Kuala_Lumpur, Asia/Famagusta, Asia/Thimphu, Asia/Rangoon, Europe/Bratislava, Asia/Calcutta, America/Argentina/Tucuman, Asia/Kabul, Indian/Cocos, Japan, Pacific/Tongatapu, America/New_York, Etc/GMT-12, Etc/GMT-11, Etc/GMT-10, SystemV/YST9YDT, Europe/Ulyanovsk, Etc/GMT-14, Etc/GMT-13, W-SU, America/Merida, EET, America/Rosario, Canada/Saskatchewan, America/St_Kitts, Arctic/Longyearbyen, America/Fort_Nelson, America/Caracas, America/Guadeloupe, Asia/Hebron, Indian/Kerguelen, SystemV/PST8PDT, Africa/Monrovia, Asia/Ust-Nera, Egypt, Asia/Srednekolymsk, America/North_Dakota/New_Salem, Asia/Anadyr, Australia/Melbourne, Asia/Irkutsk, America/Shiprock, America/Winnipeg, Europe/Vatican, Asia/Amman, Etc/UTC, SystemV/AST4ADT, Asia/Tokyo, America/Toronto, Asia/Singapore, Australia/Lindeman, America/Los_Angeles, SystemV/EST5EDT, Pacific/Majuro, America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires, Europe/Nicosia, Pacific/Guadalcanal, Europe/Athens, US/Pacific, Europe/Monaco]

Get your JVM’s current [default time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault--).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
```

> America/Los_Angeles

Be aware that the JVM's default can be changed at any moment during runtime by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM. Generally better to specify the desired/expected time zone rather than rely on system default.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

If you want to know the offset in play at a particular moment for a particular zone, ask via the `ZoneRules` object.

```
ZoneOffset offsetInEffectNow = z.getRules().getOffset( Instant.now() );
```

See all the above [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/m6vCQk).

> The bottom line is - can't rely on ID strings, must go with the offset as display ID's may vary from system to system.

No, time zone identifiers are documented and consistent. See [this list in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) tracked by the [IANA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority).

I do not know much about what `TimeZone` was doing, but if like the rest of the legacy date-time classes, it may not be wisely designed. Also not sure how your host OS and JVM was configured. Hard to diagnose as you did not provide enough information.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 5):

Joda time has a constant `DateTimeZone.UTC`. That class or constant might be of help to you.
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html

**Java 8 UPDATE**

Java 8 also now has `ZoneOffset.UTC`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC

Answer (score 2):

How about using TimeZone.getAvailableIDs() and group them by the part before the slash and make it a two step selection?

Answer (score 1):

Any timezone can be specified as "GMT" plus/minus an offset. The [timezone doc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) refers to this as a "custom ID".

To populate a drop-down, I think you'd be better off coming up with a specific list of cities/offsets, with an association to the timezone. The array returned by `getAvailableIDs()` is huge -- 586 entries in my install -- and you definitely don't want to force your users to plod through this.

Comment: Yes, the array is large, but it's not a problem. I display it sorted and it's a snap to navigate to the relevant entry. My problem is not about the size, but about confusing way the ID's are represented.

Comment: You're forgetting about daylight savings, though -- unfortunately there's lots of variation in daylight savings (aka summer time) offset rules within a single GMT offset.

Answer (score -7):

UTC is not GMT. When people (included Java educated engineering) start understanding this. GMT HAS daylight savings (yes!) UTC never changes (!). I would think that everybody should be aware of this just like the rule of leap year or leap minute.

Comment: GMT does not have daylight savings. @anonymous engineer is probably thinking of British Summer Time.

Comment: GMT doesn't change. It's close to UTC but not quite (some sort of silliness regarding leap seconds and what-not) but for most purposes, you can consider UTC to be equal to GMT.
For half the year the UK observes GMT, then during the summer it moves to BST (British Summer Time i.e. GMT + daylight savings)

Comment: **Incorrect:** [GMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time) does *not* have [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). Perhaps confusing GMT with [`Europe/London`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/London) time zone which does indeed have DST.