# Java gives me wrong time every time i try to get it

Tags: java, android, datetime

I need to get normal correct time in android application. But every time I run the app, I get wrong hours and wrong minutes. And it is not the incorrect TimeZone. Every time I run the app, the time is different! I've searched through questions here, but haven't found the answer for me. Nothing works with this... Why is it so problematic in java? In c#. for example, you can get time by just writting: `var time = DateTime.Now`. How can I get normal correct time? The time zone on my computer is set to UTC +02:00. (Ukraine, Kiev).
My code:

```
Calendar curTime = new GregorianCalendar();
curTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Ukraine/Kiev"));
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:ss");
dateFormat.setCalendar(curTime);

String time = dateFormat.format(curTime.getTime());
```

Comment: can you share some code?!

Comment: "Every time I run the app, the time is different!" Uh, what exactly are you expecting?

Comment: What is the code that you use to get the Time in android ,, @Booger don't ask about the C# code !

Comment: I've added my code into the question. Well, the thing is that, for example, now my time is 19:05. If i run the app, i get 16:54. Then, if i run it for the second time, i can get sth like 21:12

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html. You have hours and seconds set in your `dateFormat`. Try `HH:mm`.

Comment: @Voicu, i've changed my code to         `curTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+02:00"));
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");`
But it's still different from correct time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1707934/1454261) answer has some of the time zones to use in your `getTimeZone` method.

```
Calendar curTime = new GregorianCalendar();
curTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Kiev"));
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
dateFormat.setCalendar(curTime);

String time = dateFormat.format(curTime.getTime());
System.out.println(time);
```

Output:
19:22

Answer (score 0):

I hope this should work..time Zone is GMT+3 for Ukraine

```
  Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss");
  sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+3"));
  String date = sdf.format(today);
```

The output of above code ::

```
  2014-09-25-09.51.23
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me:(