# How to get a TimeZone ID from a TimeStamp Value

Tags: java, date, time, timestamp

Is it possible to get a TimeZone ID from a certain TimeStamp ? If it is please explain by a simple code.

```
 private String getDate(long timeStamp) {DateFormat objFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+4:30");
    //Instead of the Above code I want to get the TimeZone ID from my timeStamp objFormatter.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    Calendar objCalendar =
            Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
    objCalendar.setTimeInMillis(timeStamp * 1000);
    String result = objFormatter.format(objCalendar.getTime());
    objCalendar.clear();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Its duplicate question. It has been asked multiple times. FYI, check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1707934/631803

Comment: Not repeatable to my question. I have a `long timeStamp` and I want to get the TimeZone from it. In fact in no where there is even a mention to timeStamp therefore it is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Then explain your question properly. Half information is always dangerous. Also provide the code snippet, what you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TimeZone ID's in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707799/timezone-ids-in-java)

Comment: @VicJordan you can mark it as a duplicate all you want. It is not ! As I said before I want to get a TimeZone ID from a `long timestamp`

Comment: @VicJordan No, your linked Question is *not* a duplicate. It has nothing to do with a timestamp or count-from-epoch shown here. But there are likely many *other* duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tl;dr

Impossible to derive offset/zone from a count-from-epoch-in-UTC. But you can adjust *into* a zone.

```
Instant.ofEpochSecond( yourCount )
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )
```

## Avoid count-from-epoch

Firstly, avoid using a count-from-epoch number to track date-time values. Do you mean a count of whole seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds, or something else? Do you mean the [Unix/Java epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) of `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` or one of the [couple dozen other epochs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) in use by many computer systems?

Apparently you have whole seconds, and I'll assume the Unix/Java epoch.

## Impossible to get zone from count-from-epoch

You cannot “ get a TimeZone ID from a certain TimeStamp”, that is impossible. Your count-from-epoch was made while accounting for a certain time zone, usually [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). If must know that intended zone used in creating that count-from-epoch, it cannot be deduced.

Perhaps your goal is actually adjusting this count-from-epoch into a date-time for a particular region’s time zone. Read on.

## java.time

Avoid the troublesome old date-time classes such as `Date` & `Calendar` now supplanted by the java.time classes.

Convert your count-from-epoch into a point on the timeline in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( yourCount ) ;
```

Assign your desired time zone.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kabul" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/AHZiwS).

Notice the 4.5 hour difference, changing from 02:40 to 07:10, appropriate for time in Kabul. This is the same moment, the same point on the time zone, but viewed through the lens of a different region’s wall-clock time.

> input: 1500000000
>
> instant: 2017-07-14T02:40:00Z
>
> zdt: 2017-07-14T07:10+04:30[Asia/Kabul]

Comment: Thank you. This was very through and helpful answer to my question. Exactly what I needed. I am reading timestamp from a website and that website changes timestamp according to the location of the user who sent http request. I wanted to have that timestamp in my application and get the timeZone from it. Since my user may use a proxy to access that website, It would have been convenient if I could just read the TimeStamp and get the location from it but as you said it is not possible.

Comment: I use http request to fetch a website into my app then I read the TimeStamp from the website but I have no way of telling what the TimeZone might be because the user might install a proxy app on his/her cellphone.

Comment: The website calculates the TimeStamp based on the http request from the user. Since I am sending the http Request in my app, is there any way to acquire the current timeZone of the user ? Not from his/her cellphone but from the http Request.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to answer this question based on the definition of each terminology.

> What is timestamp?

Timestamp or Unix Timestamp is the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970,minus the number of leap seconds that have taken place since then.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

> Wath is Time Zone?

A time zone is a region of the earth where the same standard time is used. Each time zone is described by an identifier and usually has the format region/city (Asia/Tokyo) and an offset from Greenwich/UTC time. For example, the offset for Tokyo is +09:00. [Time Zone Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/timezones.html)

Regarding to both definitions there is no way to get a region of the earth based on a number of seconds (time), it is imperative to know from what region of the earth the time comes from.