# Why JVM shows wrong time zone for (UTC+02:00) Istanbul?

Tags: java, date, jvm, timezone, jvm-arguments

JVM does not show true date time and time zone for (UTC+02:00) Istanbul.

For example:
Now time is 12:30 PM in Istanbul.

---

Change System Time Zone to (UTC+02:00) Istanbul

System Date: 12:30 PM 03.07.2013

Java ouput:  05:00:00 VET 03.07.2013

JVM uzer.timezone: America/Caracas

---

Change System Time zone to (UTC-08:00) Pasific Time(US&Canada)

System Date: 02:30 AM 03.07.2013

Java ouput:  02:30:00 PDT 03.07.2013

JVM uzer.timezone: America/Los_Angeles

---

Change System Time zone to (UTC+02:00) Jarusalem

System Date: 12:30 PM 03.07.2013

Java ouput:  12:30:00 IDT 03.07.2013

JVM uzer.timezone: Asia/Jerusalem

---

This is my Java Environment:
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01, mixed mode)
Windows 8

Is there any one to explain this difference?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add the code you'Re using to get this results ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/))?

Comment: If you are in Venezuela, and you say: "It's 12:30pm in Istanbul", your VM translates to local time and says: "it's 5:00 am HERE". I think you are setting the Locale for a Date or a Calendar instance, not for your computer. As @UwePlonus says, show your code

Comment: If you mean Java Output: Date date = new Date(); System.out.println(date);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [known Java bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=b17ebb610a4a681d2f1c0f7e8a9bb?bug_id=7161087). It has been fixed in Java 7 update 4 (see [this bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=2217173)).

Answer (score 3):

Looking back on some other SO questions, this seems to be a Java-on-Windows problem. Please have a look at 
[How to use Java timezone id in a Windows (non-Java) application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583141/how-to-use-java-timezone-id-in-a-windows-non-java-application)
, especially answer 1, which points to a wikipedia link that may solve your mapping issue